# Parsing MongoDB query string with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I'm trying to make a MongoDb script that passes a variable name from an array of variables and then executes a query for that variable:

```
var continous = ['b', 'e', 'LBE']; //list of variables

continous.forEach(e => izracun(e));

function izracun(atr) {
    var query = '{ $group: { _id: "'+atr+'", avg: { $avg: "$'+atr+'" }, stdev: { $stdDevPop: "$'+atr+'" }, nonMissing: { $sum: 1 }}}';
    query=JSON.parse(query);
};
```

The query is constructed as a string, but when I try to JSON.parse it, I get the following error:

`[js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data...`

Variable "query" has the following value before `JSON.parse`:

`{ $group: { _id: "b", avg: { $avg: "$b" }, stdev: { $stdDevPop: "$b" }, nonMissing: { $sum: 1 }}}`

What is wrong here, why do I get that JSON.parse error? I'm planning to use the query inside `db.collection.aggregate()`

Comment: Why do you construct a *string* query just to parse it to an object afterwards? Why don't you just use an object in the first place?

Comment: Do not parse , I think the object constructed should work as it is. Give a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All keys must be surrounded by **double quotes** `"` to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) without error

```js
let queryString = '{ "$group": { "_id": "b", "avg": { "$avg": "$b" }, "stdev": { "$stdDevPop": "$b" }, "nonMissing": { "$sum": 1 }}}';
console.log(JSON.parse(queryString))
```

**Note:- If you want to include Date or Regular Expression in your query, you need to use callback function with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and convert it into desired Data type**

So, it is better option to use **Object** instead of query String.